# How to grep the logs between two date range in Unix

Tags: linux, unix

I have a log file abc.log in which each line is a date in `date +%m%d%y` format:

```
061019:12
062219:34
062319:56
062719:78
```

I want to see the all the logs between this date range (7 days before date to current date) i.e (from 062019 to 062719 in this case). The result should be:

```
062219:34
062319:56
062719:78
```

I have tried few things from my side to achieve:

```
awk '/062019/,/062719' abc.log
```

This gives me correct answer, but if i don't want to hard-code the date value and try achieving the same it does not give the correct value.

```
awk '/date --date "7 days ago" +%m%d%y/,/date +%m%d%y' abc.log
```

Note:

- `date --date "7 days ago" +%m%d%y` → `062019` (7 days back date)
- `date +%m%d%y` → `062719` (Current date)

Any suggestions how this can be achieved?

Comment: Have you tried _actually executing `date`_, e.g. something like `awk -vd1="$(date …)" -vd2="$(date …)" '$0 ~ d1,$0 ~ d2' abc.log`?

Comment: Note that your approach will only work if there’s at least one log of each of the dates present. `awk` has no concept of ‘*between*’ other that ‘*begins with and ends with*’.

Answer (score 0):

Your [middle-endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Middle-endian) date format is unfortunate for sorting and comparison purposes. `Y-m-d` would have been much easier.

Your approach using `,` ranges in awk requires exactly one log entry per day (and that the log entries are sorted chronologically).

I would use perl, e.g. something like:

```
perl -MPOSIX=strftime -ne '
    BEGIN { ($start, $end) = map strftime("%y%m%d", localtime $_), time - 60 * 60 * 24 * 7, time }
    print if /^(\d\d)(\d\d)(\d\d):/ && "$3$1$2" ge $start && "$3$1$2" le $end' abc.log
```

1. Use `strftime "%y%m%d"` to get the ends of the date range in big-endian format (which allows for lexicographical comparisons).
2. Use a regex to extract day/month/year from each line into separate variables.
3. Compare the rearranged date fields of the current line to the ends of the range to determine whether to print the line.

Answer (score 0):

To get around the issue of looking for dates that may not be there, you could generate a pattern that matches any of the dates (since there are only 8 of them it doesn’t get too big, if you want to look for the last year it might not work as well):

```sh
for d in 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
do
  pattern="${pattern:+${pattern}\\|}$(date --date "${d} days ago" +%m%d%y)"
done

grep "^\\(${pattern}\\)" abc.log
```